# Ember.js shorthand for common computed property pattern

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember.js I find myself defining computed properties that look like this:

```
someProp: function(){
  return this.get('otherProp');
}.property('otherProp')
```

or

```
someProp: function(){
  return this.get('otherObject.prop');
}.property('otherObject.prop')
```

Is there a shorter way to write computed properties that follow these patterns?

Comment: I think you meant to write **return this.get(...)** inside your method bodies?

Comment: Wenn i see these examples, i ask myself what value do they provide? In those simple examples, those methods just create some sort of alias for a given property. Or did you have something more complex in mind?

Comment: @mavilein Thanks. A habit from writing CoffeeScript...

Comment: @mavilein, yes, the first example is certainly an alias, which is sometimes necessary. The second example is a means of following the Law of Demeter, which you can google if you need an explanation of its value. I do appreciate the "questioning the question" approach, though-- it's a good way to get people to think about the problem harder.

Comment: Thanks for the keyword, something to learn again :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Having researched a little bit you could dry this a little up by doing the following with the help of **Ember.computed.alias**:

```
someProp: Ember.computed.alias("otherObject.prop")
```

You can use `alias` also to set this property. Given an Ember object which implements the property given above, you can do:

```
obj.set("someProp", "foo or whatever"); // The set will be propagated to otherObject.prop
```

[Link to Ember Source for Ember.computed.alias](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6.1/packages/ember-metal/lib/computed.js#L665)

---

**Update: Ember.computed.oneWay**

Recently a new computed property shorthand (`oneWay`) was added to Ember, which is also feasible for this requirement. The difference is that the `oneWay` shorthand **only works in the get case**. Therefore this shorthand is faster during object creation than the more complex `alias`.

```
someProp: Ember.computed.oneWay("otherObject.prop")
```

[Link to Ember Source for Ember.computed.oneWay](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6.1/packages/ember-metal/lib/computed.js#L684)

Comment: Awesome! This is even more robust that the examples I gave because it handles setting properties, not just getting them.